# Problem with Maven/Java environment on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java

I am trying to install [DSpace 6.3](https://duraspace.org/dspace/) on Ubuntu 18.04 and when I'm trying to compile maven I now get this message below:

```
becsadspace@becsadspace-OptiPlex-780:~$ mvn -U package

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Comment: Please post output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` - if undefined, you could [set it manually](https://vitux.com/how-to-setup-java_home-path-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks got it....now i want to compile maven it says build failure it needs me to point maven to pom.xml...how do i find the path for the pom.xml??

Comment: How are you running the commands? Are you in the correct directory? `mvn clean install` should work out of the box if you have navigated to the same dir as your pom.xml file.

Comment: lemme try running it on the correct directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [build failure ANT Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209401/build-failure-ant-install)